# PowerShell disable and enable a driver

Tags: powershell, driver

Sometimes after restart/coldboot I got a problem with my touchscreen driver in Win8, so I've to restart it manually by now.

So I want to write a script that starts after login, which will disable the driver and enables it again.

I actually found out to find the driver and that I can get a object list of the drivers via:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| select devicename, driverversion | where {$_.devicename -like "I2C*"}
```

But adding "`| Disable-Device`" to the end of the line will not work.

Can anyone tell me how I have to write the command correctly and start the script like an batch file?

Comment: What was the error given, when you have `| Disable-Driver` on the end?

Comment: I translate it, 

Disable-Device: The name "Disable-Device" was no name of a Cmdlet, or a function, or a script file, or an executive program. Check the notation of the name, or if it is the right path and try again.

Comment: I have a working example over at https://github.com/StingyJack/VidyaRestart

Answer (score 22):

at least with Windows 10 it is a lot easier:

```
$d = Get-PnpDevice| where {$_.friendlyname -like "I2Cwhatever*"}
$d  | Disable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false
$d  | Enable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: This is great! You could also chain all these commands directly together.

Comment: This works for me only if I run it in an admin console, otherwise I get an excepetion: … FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041001,Disable-PnpDevice

Comment: Of course you shouldn't expect _anything_ that touches device drivers to work in a standard console.

Comment: Too bad. Chaining doesn't work for me. It won't enable the device again. With three separate lines it works.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using the [Device Management cmdlets](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Device-Management-7fad2388), I'd suggest using the `Get-Device` cmdlet provided in the same pack to pass along the pipeline.

After a quick look, I found that Disable-Device doesn't take either of DeviceName or DriverVersion from the pipeline - and won't recognise either as it's only identifying parameter (`-TargetDevice`).

The technet page suggests this, to disable a device:

```
$deviceName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the Name of the Device to Disable'; Get-Device | Where-Object -Property Name -Like $deviceName | Disable-Device
```

You could simply use something like this, assuming your devicename is similar using the Get-Device cmdlet:

```
Get-Device | where {$_.name -like "I2C*"} | Disable-Device
```

Comment: An error appears by trying the your last suggestion.

"The naming "Get-Device" was no name of a Cmdlet, a function or..."

Do I have to write a full script? (I currently put this command into the powershell)

Comment: Okay, as a first step, `Disable-Device` isn't a standard cmdlet on Windows 8. If you've found it from a post like [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wincat/archive/2012/09/06/device-management-powershell-cmdlets-sample-an-introduction.aspx), you'll notice that it suggests using the Device Management cmdlets (link in answer), which contains `Disable-Device` and `Get-Device`. You'll need to download and import this module before you can use any of the commands contained within.

Comment: I tried to import the module (put in into the powershell folder modules) and "Import-Module .\PSCmdlet.psd1 -Verbose" as it says in the .txt, but it always says file not found.

Comment: Assuming you put it in one of the modules folders (e.g. `C:\Users\pewpewPenguin\Documents\WindowsPowershell\Modules`), `ipmo DeviceManagement` should import it.

Comment: now it throws this: 

`Import-Module : The 'C:\Users\pewpewPinguin\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\DeviceManagement\DeviceManagement.psd1' module c
annot be imported because its manifest contains one or more members that are not valid. The valid manifest members are
('ModuleToProcess', 'NestedModules', [...] then try to import the module again. [...]

Comment: The one named DeviceManagementCmdlet.dll doesnt work on windows 10 64bit. Try to make sure you get the one with DeviceManagement.dll.